Why is Promise.race polyfill implementation not working as expected?
I'm trying to implement Promise polyfill. I am trying to implement Promise.race but it's not working as expected. Output here should be reject to console but I'm getting nothing. Why is it not working?
I have debugged over console and for reason it never reaches the catch for MyPromise.race().
        class MyPromise{
            q;
            resolutionState; // normal, error
            currVal;
            status; // resolved,rejected,pending
            constructor(callback){
                this.q = []
                this.currVal = null
                this.status = 'pending'
                this.resolutionState = 'normal'
                this.currKind = null
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    callback(this.resolve.bind(this),this.reject.bind(this))
                })
            }

            then(callback){
                this.q.push({type:'then',callback})
                return this
            }

            catch(callback){
                this.q.push({type:'catch',callback})
                return this
            }

            executeCallbacks(){
                let i = 0;
                while(i<this.q.length){
                    // console.log('this',this)
                    if(this.resolutionState == 'normal'){
                        if(this.q[i]['type'] === 'then'){
                            try {
                                this.currVal = this.q[i]['callback'](this.currVal)
                                i++
                            } catch (error) {
                                this.resolutionState = 'error'
                                this.currVal = error
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(this.q[i]['type'] === 'catch'){
                            this.currVal = this.q[i]['callback'](this.currVal)
                            if(this.currVal)
                                this.resolutionState = 'normal'
                            i++
                        }
                        else{
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                } 
                this.q = []
            }

            resolve(arg){
                if(arg!=undefined)
                    this.currVal = arg
                this.resolutionState = 'normal'
                this.status = 'resolved'
                this.executeCallbacks()
                return this
            }

            reject(arg){
                if(arg!=undefined)
                    this.currVal = arg
                this.resolutionState = 'error'
                this.status = 'rejected'
                this.executeCallbacks()
                return this
            }

            static async race(promises){
                  return new MyPromise((res,rej)=>{
                        promises.forEach(promise => {
                            try {
                                if(promise instanceof MyPromise || promise instanceof Promise){
                                    promise.then(res).catch(rej)
                                }
                                else{
                                    res(promise)
                                }
                            } catch (error) {
                                rej(error)
                            }
                        })
                    })
            }
        }

        const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
        });

        const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
        });

        const promise3 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            reject('reject')
        })

        MyPromise.race([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((value) => {
            console.log(value);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));


If you already use static and async, then Promise.race() and native Promise should already exist on the platform. What platform is this being written for? And why not use the native Promise?

@Joseph I was inquisitive on how, whoever developed the api would have approached the problem and wanted to achieve the same behavior myself. Couldn't find the internal code as well on google so ended up asking here.

Before starting on Promise.race, you should implement then correctly. A) it takes two parameters B) it returns a new promise for the result of the callback, not this. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572 and https://promisesaplus.com

The JavaScript spec defines how Promises should work. There's also the widely-used es6-promise polyfill that you can use as reference. Referencing the entire promise spec and polyfill lib and not just Promise.race() because, as mentioned in the previous comment, you'll need to familiarize yourself with Promise behavior as a whole before diving into the methods.
